# Algolia InstantSearch - set user token for Insights

Tags: reactjs, react-native, algolia

I'd like to set a user token in my react native(expo) app for Insights. I followed the official guide(react-instantsearch-hooks) and the code below works like a charm. Just curious, how can I set a user token? What I found in the guide is for the React -
`window.aa('setUserToken', 'user-id')`

My code:

```js
import { InstantSearch } from 'react-instantsearch-hooks';

<InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName = {INDEX_NAME} insights = {true}>
  <SearchBox />
  <InfiniteHits hitComponent = {Hit}/>
</InstantSearch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Configure` from the package `react-instantsearch-core`:

```
import {Configure} from 'react-instantsearch-core'

...

<InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName = {INDEX_NAME} insights = {true}>

   // Add the below line
   <Configure clickAnalytics={true} userToken={userToken} />
   
   <SearchBox />
   <InfiniteHits hitComponent = {Hit}/>
</InstantSearch>
```